# C# Serial Receive Limit

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, arduino, serial-port

I am working on a project where I need to be able to communicate between C# and Arduino. I am stuck on an issue where I need to be able to start a timer in c# when data is received from the Arduino, then if the timer runs out, it triggers a relay to turn off power. The code looks something like this.

Arduino

```
char incoming_char=0;
#define RECEIVER_PIN A0
#define THRESHOLD 80

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //for debug
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  incoming_char=Serial.read();
  // read the input on RECEIVER_PIN
  int sensorValue = analogRead(RECEIVER_PIN);
  if( sensorValue > THRESHOLD ) {
    Serial.print("A");  //Send a letter back to VS
    }
}
```

C#

```
public void TimerTick(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Tick++;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ticking! " + Tick);
    if (Tick > 10)
    {
        UPCTimer.Stop();
    }
}
private void ArduinoSerial_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We GOT DATA!");
    if (UPCTimer.Enabled == false)
    {
        UPCTimer.Start();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We started the timer!");
        Tick = 0;
    }
```

Right now when the laser is triggered, it just spams WE GOT DATA endlessly until it the item passes through. What I would like to be able to do, is only act on the first character that's sent to VS from the Arduino, then ignore all the other input until the timer is disabled again. is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add code to the arduino firmware to wait for the analogue signal to drop below the threshold, possibly with hysteresis before allowing for data to be sent again.
Ie add a tripped variable when threshold is tripped to true or 1. Check this value when checking the threshold:

```
if( tripped == 0 && sensorValue > THRESHOLD ) 
{
    tripped = 1;
    //send A to serial port
}
else if( sensorValue < THRESHOLD - hysteresis )
{
    tripped = 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Arduino_DataReceived is an event handler.  Something has to subscribe to the event in order for it to do anything.  Somewhere in your setup code, you have a line like:

```
ArduinoSerial.DataReceived += ArduinoSerial_DataReceived;
```

If you want to ignore this data until the timer is disabled, then immediately after you say "We GOT DATA!" you can unsubscribe by adding a line like:

```
ArduinoSerial.DataReceived -= ArduinoSerial_DataReceived;
```

And then you can subscribe again once you are ready to start receiving again.

An alternate approach is to use a class-level boolean to flag when you are ignoring input.  Wrap all of your c# code in something like `if (!Ignoring) { }` and set `Ignoring` to true inside that block so that all subsequent calls are ignored.  When you are ready to start responding again, just set `Ignoring` back to false.